How to change ZIP version in Java with apache zip tool?
I'm trying to zip files in Java using apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip, it works fine but, i need my archive to be compressed with a specific zip version - 3.0, but no matter what i do, when i check it with 'zipinfo' it remains 2.0. Even though when i just use 'zip' in my command line the version is 3.0. I tried setting version like this:
      zipEntry.setVersionRequired(30);
      zipEntry.setVersionMadeBy(30);

please tell me how can fix it, without resorting to calling the command line tool from the Java app, or if there is another library that allows to change it, or if there is a way to integrate the zip cli tool into my app and it still being portable and multi platform

Wouldn't the version used be determined by the version of the API you're using? If so, it would be illegitimate to change it

What do you mean by API version? And if you mean the version of the dependency, im using the latest one

Apache is open source, you could just change it...

Why exactly do you think "i need my archive to be compressed with a specific zip version - 3.0"? It's not even clear what this means. Setting version numbers in the headers doesn't really do anything, since most unzippers ignore those anyway. Also version-required is an entirely different thing from version-made-by. The former says what zip specification features are used. The latter is just the version of the particular software used, which may have nothing to do with the features as defined in the specification.
